# alter string within angularjs expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's possible to make for exmple :

`<p>{{data.country}}</p>` print out `Country:New York`, how to alter that to `Country:NY` ?

Comment: fyi i've never heard of the country new york.

Comment: do you have the mapping from the full name to abbreviation?

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't need that, I just need a simple string alter in the view.

Comment: @AaronMusktin I think the way you want..I had implemented in the same way.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always remember that what you have inside the {{...}} is an AngularJS *expression*. That means you can call functions as well.

Just put a function on your scope like this:

```
$scope.countryTranslator = function (country) {
  if (country === 'New York') {
    return 'NY';
  }
};
```

and call it like this instead:

```
{{ countryTranslator(data.country) }}.
```

Obviously your "translator" should have better code than my example, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is bad idea, to use $scope and storage for your custom functions accessible from templates. Read https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: That is certainly one person's _opinion_ of a bad idea. I have read his guide and there are certainly areas where there is some room for opinion. For example, embedding all your components in immediately executed functions? Or controllerAs with vm?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using Regx `.match` and strings `join` method.

**Markup**

```
 {{data.country.match(pattern).join('')}}
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.data = {};
  $scope.data.country = 'New York';
  $scope.pattern = /\b(\w)/g;
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/SW48egnfaJtIOxX2fZS5?p=preview)

Comment: ah this is way too complicated.

Comment: But the solution of pankajparkar, is better

Comment: @AaronMusktin I don't think so its hard..If you want to increase its readability then you could move this code to custom filter as wZVang did..

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom filter:

```
.filter("countryCaps", function(){
  return function(country){
    return "Country: " + country.match(/[A-Z]/g).join("")
  }
})
```

```
<p>{{data.country | countryCaps}}</p>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3no9gVcSdc6uzKAw8Xt2?p=preview)**

Answer (score -1):

You should use [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) for this purpose.

But you still have a problem with database of cities full name and they shortcuts, for this purpose, you can use static json file, or use side server service in your choice.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Custom filter is one of the way to do it, I'm asking it's possible to do it with view, I know how to achieve that in the model layer too.

Comment: @AaronMusktin don't do that, really. View should present info not to alter it, you should format it in any way in model. I guess you should read code style too https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: @DanielA.White everything matters, he could not use filters if he didn't read that article. Should I copy paste full article there?